# C# Создание программы для обработки изображений

Tags: c#, изображения, графика

Мне нужно написать программу, которая будет обрабатывать изображение. Встал вопрос как сделать функцию, которая будет делать илюзию, что изображение выпуклое, либо наоборот вогнутое. Например такая функция есть в программе Paint.NET.
Желательно использовать Graphics, но если есть любые примеры как это реализовать буду рад почитать. Если есть примеры на других языках, тоже буду рад посмотреть.Входные данные:
[image: Входные данные]
Выходные данные:
[image: Выходные данные]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не по теме: раньше смотрел тебя, даже делал свои бинды на NetLimiter 4, для кристы